# Got a different proof, want to check if it's right

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to check if my new proof of the following statement is valid.

**Problem Statement:** Let $V=F^n$ be the space of column vectors. Prove that every subspace $W$ of $V$ is the space of solutions of some system of homogeneous linear equations $AX=0$.

**My proof:** Let $A$ be an $m$ x $n$ matrix. If $A$ is nonsingular, then $AX=0$ has only the trivial solution, and both $\{0\}$ and span$\{0\}$ are in $F^n$. If $A$ is singular, then let **B** be the basis for the set of solutions to $AX=0$. Since each $X$ is an element of $F^n$, **B** is a subset of $F^n$ and thus span($B$) is a subset of $F^n$. Therefore, we have proven our claim.

I hope this is right. I've been working on this problem all day.

Comment: How do you know that there isn't a subspace $W$ that isn't formed that way?

Comment: Your proof seems to a proof that solutions of a system $AX = 0$ are subspaces of $V$, whereas the statement you said you wanted to prove is the reverse.

Comment: Arrrgh... help me please

Comment: Take a subspace $W$ of $V$. Can you construct a matrix $A$ such that $AX = 0$ if and only if $X \in W$?

Comment: Yes we can, if X is the trivial solution and A is invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is  strange. As  Daniel Mclaury said, it seems that  you prove  that every  space solution of a homogeneous system is a subspace of Fn, But  you take a basis for this space , so you already consider the solution  space as a subspace.